# PHP preg_replace with exclusion blacklist array of negative patterns

Tags: php, regex, regexp-replace

I would like to change some (short) strings, eg.: rz -> ż, ch -> h
appearing in the searched sentence, but excluding those appearing
on the blacklist in the form of (wider) regular patterns.

For example, I have a polish sentence (or any other) at the input:

```
Tarzan się tarza a tarzanie jest głupie
```

I would like to replace all these digraphs:

```
rz -> ż
```

but excluding such from a separate blacklist of the negative patterns, eg:

```
$blacklist = [
    '/\bta(rz)an(?:|a|ach|ami|em|om|owi|ow|y)\b/ui',
    '/\bTa(rz)anie\b/u',

//  ... and few more others
];
```

For now, I'm doing it so, that I first find all the offsets of the occurrences of rz,
I create an array of $found from them and then, in a for ($blacklist as $pattern) loop
I eliminate those found with preg_match_all. At the end I only replace
those, whose offset remains in the $found array. It seems ineffective to me
at least not elegant, and I have a feeling that it can be done somehow better.

Comment: Does https://ideone.com/NwVxJ4 work as expected?

Comment: I made a mistake in defining the exceptions list. It was supposed to be:
     $ blacklist = [
         '/\bta(rz)an(?:|a|ach|ami|em|om|owi|ow|y)\b/ui',
         '/\bTa(rz)anie\b/u',
     ]
Your answer is almost exactly what I expected and certainly the answer to the problem defined by me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
$text = "Tarzan się tarza a tarzanie jest głupie";
$blacklist = ['\bta(rz)an(?:|a|ach|ami|em|om|owi|ow|y)\b', '\b(?i:Tarzanie)\b'];
echo preg_replace('/(?:' . implode('|', $blacklist) . ')(*SKIP)(*F)|rz/u', 'ż', $text);
// => Tażan się taża a tarzanie jest głupie
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/7D8VF6) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rTS3Lx/3).

*Details*:

- `(?:\bta(rz)an(?:|a|ach|ami|em|om|owi|ow|y)\b|\bTa(rz)anie\b)` - either of

  - `\btarzan(?:|a|ach|ami|em|om|owi|ow|y)\b` - word boundary, `tarzan` and then an optional `a`, `ach`, `ami`, `em`, `om`, `owi`, `ow`, `y` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\b(?i:Tarzanie)\b` - case insensitive matching of the whole word `Tarzanie`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skip the match and go on to search for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `rz` - a `rz` substring.

Comment: Can it be applied to different case sensitive / insensitive patterns?

Comment: @kruk You may. Use inline modifier groups. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I have heard of such a pattern (*SKIP)(*F)

Comment: @kruk See my [`SKIP-FAIL` regex technique explanation YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvZ7knJVYW0).